# Ordering by date in mySQL not working with a simple query?

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to order a list of MySQL results by date, putting on top the more recent ones.

This is my query (I've added the formatted date field in order to easily see if the order shown is correct):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT contenidoID, titulo, fecha, 
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha), '%d-%m-%Y') AS date
  FROM contenidos
  WHERE publicado = 1
  ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

The **fecha** field is a **string** field.

### The expected result is:

```
2886 | pagina estática                                      | 1525662000 | 06-05-2018
1012 | Plan aprender conectados                             | 1525274828 | 02-05-2018
1011 | En el día del trabajador, una historia               | 1525191654 | 01-05-2018
 485 | Sobre la Corte Suprema de Justicia                   | 1524932656 | 28-04-2018
 484 | Empresa de electrodomésticos responde                | 1524925652 | 28-04-2018 
 483 | La obra social debe cubrir los gastos de escolaridad | 1524658737
```

### The result that I get is:

```
1419 | Obligaciones de los Propietarios                     |  982428253 | 17-02-2001
1092 | Modificaciones al Código Contravencional             |  965444400 | 04-08-2000
2222 | Ley de Expropiaciones de la CABA                     |  962060969 | 26-06-2000
2886 | pagina estática                                      | 1525662000 | 06-05-2018
1012 | Plan aprender conectados                             | 1525274828 | 02-05-2018
1011 | En el día del trabajador, una historia               | 1525191654 | 01-05-2018
 485 | Sobre la Corte Suprema de Justicia                   | 1524932656 | 28-04-2018
 484 | Empresa de electrodomésticos responde                | 1524925652 | 28-04-2018
 483 | La obra social debe cubrir los gastos de escolaridad | 1524658737
```

**Why are those old results appearing at the top of the list?!**

**IS THIS A DUPLICATED POST?** I've been reading quite a few date issues with mysql responses here before I've posted this message, but in all cases I've found that the query was somehow more complex and the answer didn't apply to this, or there was some PHP code involved. I'll be more than happy to close this in case there's out there an actual answer for this and someone can point that out to me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update with the schema of your table? From the result you get, it seems the date is not of type TIMESTAMP, but a string one. I'm supposing that because numbers are sorted in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Answer (score -1):

Just in case it helps someone, what I've found is that the problem was in the ORDER BY clause, because that should have the format as well.

This solved the problem for me.

```
  ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha) DESC
```

Comment: Um, no. That's not it.

Comment: This can happen if *fecha* is not of TIMESTAMP type but a string one. For example, VARCHAR

Comment: Thanks @Miguel You're right, I just realized that in the database it was set as a string. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Strawberry, well, the actual solution would be useful :)

Comment: Well, the actual facts would be useful